# Encoded Commas ignored and being converted to array

Tags: java, spring, url, url-encoding

I need to have encoded commas ignored by the spring framework but have regular commas treated as an array.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/name/details", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<NameObj> getNameDetails(
@RequestParam(value = "searchLevel", required = true) Integer searchLevel,
@RequestParam(value = "searchValue", required = true) String searchValue,
@RequestParam(value = "address", required = false) String[] address)
```

I am sending a url like

```
/name/details?searchLevel=5&searchValue=Tom&address=5%20Tomberry%20Way%2CState
```

Where %2C is the encoded comma.  I need this to understand that some people can have several addresses to them that is comma delimited and to split that into an array but anytime an encoded comma comes in, to treat it as a regular string so for EX:

```
 /name/details?searchLevel=5&searchValue=Tom&address=5%20Tomberry%20Way%2CState,10%20Blimey%20Way%2CState
```

Would be treated as an array of addresses.
The only solution I've found for this is to completely change how Spring interprets commas and use ';' instead.  The problem is this is part of a much larger web-app that is already using a comma separator in different parts of the app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!